# Create instance of the class from base class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have DataAccess class which is derived from DataAccessor. DataAccessor class is the DB base class which I use in all all projects.

Instance method is the helper to create new instance of the DataAccess class. I would like to move Instance method to DataAccessor base class and create new insatnces of derived classes from base class. How to do that?

```
public class DataAccess : DataAccessor
{

    public static DataAccess Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return new DataAccess();
        }
    }
}

public abstract class DataAccessor 
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Base<T> where T : new()
{
    public static T Instance
    {
        get { return new T(); }
    }
}

public class Derived : Base<Derived>
{
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Can you point me at an example somewhere of something like this being used?

Comment: I can use this class to create integers. int foo = Base<int>.Instance; What about that?

Comment: @iandotkelly, personally the only thing I can think of, off the bat, is a generic singleton implementation.  But we all know how bad they are :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice: this is not Singleton, this is Factory. Singleton is when you can only call new once.

Comment: @GFK, I am aware of that.  iandotkelly asked why you might use something like this, obviously in the singleton case there would be a private static member and a check.

Comment: @Tomas - I know you've accepted this as the answer, but really I'm not convinced this is a great solution to any problem.  I'm not fishing for rep, just trying to persuade you away from a solution heavily relying on inheritance and worse, the base class knowing about the sub-classes.  I'm not going to vote down the solution, as its pretty much exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)?